# can i get unity web player in ubuntu GNOME

Tags: software-installation, plugins

currently i am using ubuntu gnome 14.04 and i want to the way to install unity web player as many applications online needs that plugin to be installed in order to display some graphics or games. I also have WINE installed in my pc so can i download a windows version of it and use it for gnome environment

Comment: i dont think so

Comment: but why like that

Comment: i have tried downloading it but it is available only in windows

Comment: but i have wine installed can't i run it with  wine

Comment: better try doing the same thing as you said

Comment: i am not getting it i have installed it via wine but how to enable the plugin